# In (server) GTM, how can I make a tag trigger when a path on the event is present and it doesn't contain a specific value?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

This Javascript describes the desired behavior, but sGTM doesn't allow Javascript variables:

```
(e.ud && ('country' in e.ud) && (e.ud.country != 'us'))
```

It is important for the trigger to fire when e.ud.country is null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a Variable Template that runs basically the above code.

```js
const getAllEventData = require('getAllEventData');
const eventData = getAllEventData();
if (!eventData) { return false; }
const isCountryDefined = eventData.hasOwnProperty('country');
const isCountryNotUs = (eventData.country != 'us');
return (isCountryDefined && isCountryNotUs) ? 1 : 0;
```

I made a variable based on the template, and a trigger based on the variable, and (naturally) used that trigger on my tag.